# How to create a chart-js pie chart with PHP data variables?

Tags: php, variables, pie-chart, chart.js

I am creating a pie chart using chart.js; however, the value I want in the pie chart is a PHP variable. How do I add it to the pie chart? Currently I have this for the data for the pie chart:

```
var pieData = [
            {
                value: 40,
                color:"green"
            },
            {
                value : 40,
                color : "red"
            }
        ];
```

However, I need to replace the two 40s with PHP variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP echo function for this. You can concatenate your PHP variables into the echo statement. Note: If you want to send an array to the JS, just use `json_encode()` like shown below.

**PHP section:**

```
<?php
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
var v1=40;
var c1="green";
var v2=40;
var c2="red";
var jsArray =' . json_encode($phpArray) . '; // Remove this if not needed...
</script>';
?>
```

**Javascript section:**

```
var pieData = [
    {
        value: v1,
        color: c1
    },
    {
        value : v2,
        color : c2
    }
];
```

You can wrap everything in a function for cleaner code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep, good answer. However I would advise against wrapping JavaScript (or HTML) in `echo` statements - it prevents your editing environment from understanding (and validating) your document. A nice trick is just to move the JavaScript to a PHP file, and then to `require` it, ensuring the `$phpArray` variable is set beforehand. You can then just do `<?php echo json_encode($phpArray) ?>` at the appropriate point.

Comment: How can I then use the $phparray to extract the values into javascript?

Comment: Just use jsArray[0], jsArray[1], ... etc. in JS code. Or, you can iterate using for(var i=0; j<yourarraysize; i++) { console.log(jsArray[i]); } or use forEach.